# Unit-testing Spring applications using Scala's Specs

Tags: spring, scala, junit, specs

We have a large infrastructure that's highly dependent on Spring Framework. Recently I began writing code in Scala and test it using Specs. This is all great but at some point I need to use Spring-dependent features (Such as a HibernateDaoSupport-based DAO).

Has anyone managed to use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class to run Specs tests? Does anyone have a different direction as to how to achieve this goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've struggled with the class runner in a similarly awkward scenario once and then I created a [MethodRule implementation called TemporarySpringContext](http://iweinfuld.posterous.com/simplifying-spring-integration-testing) that could also solve your problem I think.

Comment: Not *exactly* the solution I was looking for but good enough, I suppose